# Scanning certificates store does not show all certificates

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, x509certificate

I created a C#.Net console program listed below to scan all Certificate Stores and show Certificate information. The problem is that it is not showing all certificates.

For example, this command line shows Certificates in the Personal Store:

```
CERTUTIL.EXE -store My
```

However my test program shows it as having no Personal certificates. I am using Windows 2008 R2.  Here is the abbreviated console app. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I tried both in a regular CMD Window, and As Administrator with the same results.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Collections;

namespace CertView
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stores = Enum.GetValues(typeof(StoreName));
            IEnumerator enumStores = stores.GetEnumerator();
            foreach (StoreName sn in stores)
            {
                X509Store str = new X509Store(sn.ToString());
                str.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                int count = str.Certificates.Count;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Store: " + sn.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                    foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in str.Certificates)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Friendly name: {0}", x509.FriendlyName);
                        Console.WriteLine("Issued to: " + x509.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false));
                        Console.WriteLine("Issued by: " + x509.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, true));
                        Console.WriteLine("Thumbprint: " + x509.Thumbprint);
                        x509.Reset();
                    }
                }
                str.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `certutil` by default focuses on `LocalMachine` store, while `X509Store` focuses on `CurrentUser` store. Read remarks section on `X509Store` constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h16bc8wd(v=vs.110).aspx

You need to use different constructor where you specify the store location. For example, this one: X509Store(StoreName, StoreLocation)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: @NeilWeicher To list CurrentUser\My certificates using certutil run the command `certutil -user- store my`

Comment: Thanks. How do you explicitly specify LocalMachine, or is that just the default?  I tried -LocalMachine, -System, and a bunch of others.

Comment: In certutil, if "-user" switch is not presented, Local Machine is assumed by default in all cases.